# select rows with condition of date presto

Tags: sql, presto

I try to select by hour the number of impression for a particular day :

I try with this code :

```
SELECT 
    date_trunc('hour', CAST(date_time AS timestamp)) date_time,
    COUNT(impression_id) AS count_impression_id
FROM
    parquet_db.imp_pixel
WHERE
    date_time = '2022-07-27' 
LIMIT 100
GROUP BY 1
```

But I got this error when I add the "where" clause :

> line 5:1: mismatched input 'group'. Expecting:

Can you help me to fix it? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIMIT` usually comes *last* in a SQL query.  Also, you should not be using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY`.  Use this version:

```sql
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('hour', CAST(date_time AS timestamp)) date_time,
       COUNT(impression_id) AS count_impression_id
FROM parquet_db.imp_pixel
WHERE CAST(date_time AS date) = '2022-07-27'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY <something>
LIMIT 100;
```

Note that the `ORDER BY` clause determines *which* 100 records you get in the result set.  Your current (intended) query lets Presto decide on its own which 100 records get returned.

Comment: than you, I try your version but it tells me that there is no data to show, but i see that there multiple rows with date_time '2022-07-27', strange..

Comment: Typo: My `WHERE` clause was wrong.  Please try it again.

Comment: If `date_time` be _already_ a timestamp, then you don't need to cast it in your select clause.